# Installation of Windows 10 in Virtualbox stalls at logo

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, virtualbox

I'm trying to install Windows 10 in Virtualbox on a Ubuntu host. I've downloaded the ISO from the [Windows website](https://www.microsoft.com/nl-nl/software-download/windows10ISO). After starting up the new VM, I see the blue Windows logo on a black background, and nothing happens. I've tried several times, waited for half an hour, no change.

VM settings are default, except network is set to bridge, which I normally use to get the system visible on the local network.

[image: Windows 10 in Virtualbox]

How can I get this working?

Comment: Same problem here for at least one year already. Changing settings like EFI or PAE/NX all did not help. Only installing it in VMWare and then importing the image in VirtualBox worked until now. Have you found out something in the meantime?